# MultiDataTrigger with multiple ComboBoxes WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, multidatatrigger

I would like to enable button only when all specified `ComboBoxes` have values. However, as soon as I add a second condition, button is enabled from the start

Here is my code

```
<Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorPartNumberComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorTypeComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorBrandNameComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=DimmingProtocolComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Wired_WirelessComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiDataTrigger` requires *all* of the conditions to be true for it to take effect. I.e. it's equivalent to a logical AND.

In your example, if *any* value is non-null, the trigger won't take effect and the button will remain enabled.

For a logical OR, instead of using `MultiDataTrigger`, just use multiple `DataTrigger`. If any condition of any trigger is true, then that trigger will take effect, with precedence over the default setter for the property in the style.

For example:

```xml
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorPartNumberComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <DataTrigger/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorTypeComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <DataTrigger/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SensorBrandNameComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <DataTrigger/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DimmingProtocolComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <DataTrigger/>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Wired_WirelessComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <DataTrigger/>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

Alternatively, you might consider putting the logic in your view model, with a single `bool` property you bind to, and which is set according to the bound `SelectedValue` properties for the various `ComboBox` controls.

Yet another alternative would be to use `MultiBinding` to bind the five view model properties that are bound to the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` properties, with a `IMultiValueConverter` that implements the logic.

Of course, these last two options work only if you've got a proper view model with binding set up in the first place (something I strongly encourage, if you haven't already).